# HBase get returns old values even with max versions = 1

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have the desire to find the columns that have not been updated for more than a specific time period.

So I want to do a scan against the columns with a timerange. 
The normal behaviour of HBase is that you then get the latest value in that time range (which is not what I want).

As far as I understand the way HBase should work is that if you set the maximum number of versions for the values in a column family to '1' it should retain only the last value that was put into the cell.

What I found is different.

If I do the following commands into the hbase shell

```
create 't1', {NAME => 'c1', VERSIONS => 1}
put 't1', 'r1', 'c1', 'One', 1000
put 't1', 'r1', 'c1', 'Two', 2000
put 't1', 'r1', 'c1', 'Three', 3000
get 't1', 'r1'
get 't1', 'r1' , {TIMERANGE => [0,1500]}
```

the result is this:

```
get 't1', 'r1'
COLUMN                     CELL
 c1:                       timestamp=3000, value=Three
1 row(s) in 0.0780 seconds

get 't1', 'r1' , {TIMERANGE => [0,1500]}
COLUMN                     CELL
 c1:                       timestamp=1000, value=One
1 row(s) in 0.1390 seconds
```

Why does the second query return a value eventhough I've set the max versions to only 1?

The HBase version I currently have installed here is HBase 0.94.6-cdh4.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a bug in hbase.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-10102

Comment: Note, that bug is closed as "Won't Fix."

Comment: Yes, fixing this effect would yield too many bad side effects.