# Reading only the latest values in a row via HBase get

Tags: java, hbase

Given this data:

```
row_key          cf1:c1           cf1:c2           timestamp
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    1              x                            t1
    1                               y           t2
```

The HBase [get](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Get.html) returns both x and y. I would normally expect it to return only y ( because that is the latest timestamp ). But that is not what happens.

There are several alternatives to work around this problem.

1. Use get.setMaxVersions(1). However, [this doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425707/hbase-get-returns-old-values-even-with-max-versions-1).
2. Use get.setTimestamp(long timestamp). However, [this is not a good idea either](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/88858/hbase-how-to-get-max-timestamp-of-a-table.html).
3. Disable versioning on the table. This is what I am going to do if there is no better solution.

I am hoping I am just missing a simple/easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the versioning is being misunderstood here. Though the version (metadata) is maintained at ColumnFamily level, the versions are maintained at cell level. So in your example, cf1:c1 is having only one version so during your scan, obviously that will be the latest version cell.

To explain in detail, please refer the attached screenshot below.

[image]

1. We one cell each for cf1:c1 and cf1:c2 as explained by you.
2. Next we are inserting another record in cf1:c1, so this creates another cell and it has the latest version timestamp.
3. So if you scan the table for multiple versions you can see that cf1:c1 holds two cells with different version
4. If you get only the latest version during scan, you will be getting "z" as the value as it is having the latest version cell for cf1:c1

I understood by going through [HBase version in document](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/versions.html), may be it can help you too.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I got to 't2' via 'table.delete' on c1 first. There is no reason I should get back x on the next read.

Comment: @PrashantSaraswat : So do you mean that you have deleted a cell, but still able to see that? Can you please describe your table and share the output.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be resolved using 'DependentColumnFilter' provided by HBase.
DependentColumnFilter helps reads only the columns with latest timestamp.
So, all the columns having only the latest timestamp will get fetched.

If you just scan the hbase table on the hbase shell, still you will see the "null" column having a value, but the timestamp will be old.

PS: this filter must be applied on a column that will be not-null always (as per your business).